# Why doesn't the try catch block catch the promise exception?

Tags: javascript, exception, es6-promise

I'm confused about error handling with promises. The answer might be obvious, but I'm not getting it.

I have the following example code:

```js
var test = async function(){
  throw new Error('Just another error')
}

try {
  test().then()
}
catch(err){
  alert('error: ' + err.toString())
}
```

In my browser I don't get an alert and `Uncaught (in promise) Error` in the console. Why is that? Shouldn't the try..catch block handle the error?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I can see two possible aspects to your question:

1. The error being thrown in `test` is in the synchronous (not asynchronous) part of `test`. Why is it a promise rejection rather than a synchronous exception?
2. The promise from `test()` is being rejected, why doesn't `catch` catch that rejection?

#### #1 - Why is it a rejection?

Because even if an `async` function throws during the synchronous portion of its work, that just rejects the promise it returns, it *doesn't* raise a synchronous error. It's just a design decision made during the design of `async` functions, and a smart one — if it were a synchronous error when throwing in the synchronous part of the function but a promise rejection after that, it would be chaotic and hard to understand. So it's simple: throwing in an `async` function always rejects its promise.

(This is consistent with how the promise constructor treats the executor callback you pass into it. When you do `new Promise((resolve, reject) => /*...*/})`, the promise constructor calls your function synchronously, but if you throw during the call, it uses what you throw to reject the promise rather than allowing it to continue as a synchronous exception.)

#### #2 - Why isn't rejection caught by the `catch` block?

Because you're not using `await`. Promise rejections are only exceptions when you are `await`ing the promise. If you use the promise methods `then`/`catch`/`finally` to attach handlers, rejection is handled by calling the rejection handler, not by the exception mechanism.

So either use promise methods to attach fulfillment and rejection handlers:

```
test()
.then(result => {
    // ...use `result` here...
})
.catch(error => {
    // ...handle/report error here...
});
```

Or use `await` in an `async` function (or at the top level of a module if you have top-level `await` in your enviroment):

```
// In an `async` function (or the top level of a module in cutting-edge environments)
try {
    const result = await test();
    // ...use `result` here...
}
catch(err){
    // ...handle/report error here...
}
```

Comment: FWIW, I go into promises in depth in Chapter 8 of my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys*, and I go into `async`/`await` right after in Chapter 9. Links in my profile if you're interested.

Comment: Ah, now I got it. Thanks a lot for the quick reply!

Comment: @timrosskamp - You're welcome! I realized you might have been asking a slightly different question than I answered and was editing when you accepted the answer. So apparently I did answer what you were asking, but FWIW there's a bit more there now. :-) Happy coding!

Comment: Even better. My question was indeed #2. But your other explanation is also a good to thing to keep in mind and something I didn't knew.